# Issue with the @font-face css technique

Tags: html, css, font-face

Can't seem to find out why my font is not showing up. I followed standard procedure but now luck.

Live Sute
http://chownow.jlgstudiodesign.com/

I am trying to use a specific font in the navigation bar of a wordpress site. I have the font in it's own directory. The font is called red circle.

css:

```
#art-main, table{    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;    font-size: 13px;}
@font-face {
    font-family:'RedCircleRegular';
    src: url('http://jlgstudiodesign.com/chownow/wp-content/themes/chownowv4/font/redcircl-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://jlgstudiodesign.com/chownow/wp-content/themes/chownowv4/font/redcircl-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('http://jlgstudiodesign.com/chownow/wp-content/themes/chownowv4/font/redcircl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://jlgstudiodesign.com/chownow/wp-content/themes/chownowv4/font/redcircl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://jlgstudiodesign.com/chownow/wp-content/themes/chownowv4/font/redcircl-webfont.svg#webfontcTejbeSF') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, ul, ol, li{    margin: 0;    padding: 0;}

body{  margin: 0 auto;  padding: 0;  color: #080D03;  background-color: #000000;}

.art-postcontent,.art-postcontent li,.art-postcontent table,.art-postcontent a,.art-postcontent a:link,.art-postcontent a:visited,.art-postcontent a.visited,.art-postcontent a:hover,.art-postcontent a.hovered{    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;}

.art-postcontent p{    margin: 12px 0 12px 0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a,h1 a:link, h2 a:link, h3 a:link, h4 a:link, h5 a:link, h6 a:link,h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited, h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited,h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover{  font-family: "Red Circle",Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  font-size: 32px;}

.art-postcontent a{  text-decoration: none;  color: #673190;}
.art-postcontent a:link{  text-decoration: none;  color: #673190;}
.art-postcontent a:visited, .art-postcontent a.visited{  color: #673190;}
.art-postcontent  a:hover, .art-postcontent a.hover{  text-decoration: underline;  color: #6C2D62;}
.art-postcontent h1{   margin: 21px 0 21px 0;    color: #000000; }
.art-postcontent h2{    color: #000000;   margin: 19px 0 19px 0;    font-size: 24px;   }
.art-postcontent h3{   margin: 19px 0 19px 0;   color: #000000;   font-size: 19px;    }
.art-postcontent h4{   margin: 20px 0 20px 0;    color: #000000;    font-size: 16px;   }
.art-postcontent h5{   margin: 26px 0 26px 0;    color: #000000;      font-size: 13px;}
.art-postcontent h6{   margin: 35px 0 35px 0;    color: #000000;   font-size: 11px;      }
ul{  list-style-type: circle;}ol{  list-style-position: inside;}
#art-main{  position: relative;  width: 100%;  left: 0;  top: 0;  cursor:default;}
.cleared{  float: none;  clear: both;  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  border: none;  font-size: 1px;}
form{  padding: 0 !important;  margin: 0 !important;}
table.position{  position: relative;  width: 100%;  table-layout: fixed;}
/* end Page *//* begin Box, Sheet */
.art-sheet{  position: relative;  margin: 0 auto;  min-width: 11px;  min-height: 11px;}
.art-sheet-body{  position: relative;  padding: 5px;}
.art-sheet-tr, .art-sheet-tl, .art-sheet-br, .art-sheet-bl, .art-sheet-tc, .art-sheet-bc,.art-sheet-cr, .art-sheet-cl{  position: absolute;}
.art-sheet-tr, .art-sheet-tl, .art-sheet-br, .art-sheet-bl{  font-family:'RedCircleRegular'; width: 10px;  height: 10px;  background-image: url('images/sheet_s.png');}.art-sheet-tl{  top: 0;  left: 0;  clip: rect(auto, 5px, 5px, auto);}.art-sheet-tr{  top: 0;  right: 0;  clip: rect(auto, auto, 5px, 5px);}.art-sheet-bl{  bottom: 0;  left: 0;  clip: rect(5px, 5px, auto, auto);}.art-sheet-br{  bottom: 0;  right: 0;  clip: rect(5px, auto, auto, 5px);}.art-sheet-tc, .art-sheet-bc{  left: 5px;  right: 5px;  height: 10px;  background-image: url('images/sheet_h.png');}.art-sheet-tc{  top: 0;  clip: rect(auto, auto, 5px, auto);}.art-sheet-bc{  bottom: 0;  clip: rect(5px, auto, auto, auto);}.art-sheet-cr, .art-sheet-cl{  top: 5px;  bottom: 5px;  width: 10px;  background-image: url('images/sheet_v.png');}.art-sheet-cr{  right: 0;  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 5px);}.art-sheet-cl{  left: 0;  clip: rect(auto, 5px, auto, auto);}.art-sheet-cc{  position: absolute;  top: 5px;  left: 5px;  right: 5px;  bottom: 5px;  background-color: #8CC540;}.art-sheet{  top: 50px !important;  margin-bottom: 50px !important;  cursor:auto;  width: 805px;}/* end Box, Sheet *//* begin Header */div.art-header{  margin: 0 auto;  position: relative;  width: 100%;  height: 146px;  overflow: hidden;}div.art-header-center{  position: relative; width: 795px;   left:50%;}div.art-header-jpeg{  position: absolute;  top: 0;  left:-50%;  width: 795px;  height: 146px;  background-image: url('images/header.jpg');  background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: center center;}/* end Header *//* begin Logo */div.art-logo{  display: block;  position: absolute;  left: 10px;  top: 20px;  width: 500px;}h1.art-logo-name{  display: none;  text-align: {HorizontalAlign};}h1.art-logo-name, h1.art-logo-name a, h1.art-logo-name a:link, h1.art-logo-name a:visited, h1.art-logo-name a:hover{  font-size: 28px;  text-decoration: none;  padding: 0;  margin: 0;  color: {NameFontColor} !important;}h2.art-logo-text, h2.art-logo-text a,h2.art-logo-text a:link,h2.art-logo-text a:visited,h2.art-logo-text a:hover{  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  font-size: 14px;  padding: 0;  margin: 0;  color: {TextFontColor} !important;}h2.art-logo-text{  display: none;  text-align: {HorizontalAlign};}/* end Logo *//* begin Menu */
/* menu structure */
/* menu structure */
.art-menu{  border-bottom: 5px solid white;  padding: 0 0 0 0;}
.art-nav{  position: relative;  min-height: 34px;  z-index: 100;}
.art-nav .l, .art-nav .r{  position: absolute;  z-index: -1;  top: 0;  height: 100%;  background-image: url('images/nav.png');}
.art-nav .l{  left: 0;  right: 0;}
.art-nav .r{  right: 0;  width: 795px;  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 795px);}/* end Menu */
/* begin MenuItem */

.art-menu a{  position: relative;  display: block;  overflow: hidden;  height: 34px;  cursor: pointer;  text-decoration: none;}
.art-menu ul li{  font-family:'RedCircleRegular';  margin:0;    clear: both;}
.art-menu a .r, .art-menu a .l{  position: absolute;  display: block;  top: 0;  z-index: -1;  height: 112px;  background-image: url('images/menuitem.png');}
.art-menu a .l{  left: 0;  right: 0;}.art-menu a .r{  width: 400px;  right: 0;  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 400px);}
.art-menu a .t, .art-menu ul a, .art-menu a, .art-menu a:link, .art-menu a:visited, .art-menu a:hover{  font-family:'RedCircleRegular';  font-size: 16px;  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;}
.art-menu a .t{  color: #FFFFFF;  padding: 0 8px;  margin: 0 0;  line-height: 34px;  text-align: center;}
.art-menu a:hover .l, .art-menu a:hover .r{  top: -39px;}
.art-menu li:hover>a .l, .art-menu li:hover>a .r{  top: -39px;}
.art-menu li:hover a .l, .art-menu li:hover a .r{  top: -39px;}
.art-menu a:hover .t{  color: #7DBD28;}
.art-menu li:hover a .t{  color: #7DBD28;}.art-menu li:hover>a .t{  color: #7DBD28;}.art-menu a.active .l, .art-menu a.active .r{  top: -78px;}.art-menu a.active .t{  color: #FFFFFF;}
/* end MenuItem *//* begin MenuSeparator */.art-menu .art-menu-li-separator{  display: block;  width: 0;  height:34px;}/* end MenuSeparator *//* begin MenuSubItem */.art-menu ul a{  display: block;  text-align: center;  white-space: nowrap;  height: 32px;  width: 180px;  overflow: hidden;  line-height: 32px;  background-image: url('images/subitem.png');  background-position: left top;  background-repeat: repeat-x;  border-width: 2px;  border-style: solid;  border-color: #FFFFFF;}.art-nav ul.art-menu ul span, .art-nav ul.art-menu ul span span{  display: inline;  float: none;  margin: inherit;  padding: inherit;  background-image: none;  text-align: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}.art-menu ul a, .art-menu ul a:link, .art-menu ul a:visited, .art-menu ul a:hover, .art-menu ul a:active, .art-nav ul.art-menu ul span, .art-nav ul.art-menu ul span span{  text-align: left;  text-indent: 12px;  text-decoration: none;  line-height: 32px;  color: #FFFFFF;  font-size: 12px;  margin:0;  padding:0;}.art-menu ul li a:hover{  color: #7DBD28;  border-color: #FFFFFF;  background-position: 0 -32px;}.art-menu ul li:hover>a{  color: #7DBD28;  border-color: #FFFFFF;  background-position: 0 -32px;}.art-nav .art-menu ul li a:hover span, .art-nav .art-menu ul li a:hover span span{  color: #7DBD28;}.art-nav .art-menu ul li:hover>a span, .art-nav .art-menu ul li:hover>a span span{  color: #7DBD28;}/* end MenuSubItem *//* begin Layout */.art-content-layout{  display: table;  width: 100%;  table-layout: fixed;  border-collapse: collapse;  background-color: Transparent;  border: none !important;  padding:0 !important;}.art-layout-cell, .art-content-layout-row{  background-color: Transparent;  vertical-align: top;  text-align: left;  border: none !important;  margin:0 !important;  padding:0 !important;}.art-content-layout .art-content-layout{width: auto;margin:0;}.art-content-layout .art-layout-cell, .art-content-layout .art-layout-cell .art-content-layout .art-layout-cell{display: table-cell;}.art-layout-cell .art-layout-cell{display: block;}.art-content-layout-row {display: table-row;}.art-layout-glare{position:relative;}/* end Layout *//* begin Box, Block */.art-block{  position: relative;  margin: 0 auto;  min-width: 1px;  min-height: 1px;}.art-block-body{  position: relative;  padding: 0;}.art-block{  margin: 10px;}/* end Box, Block *//* begin BlockHeader */.art-blockheader{  margin-bottom: 0;}.art-blockheader, .art-blockheader h3.t{  position: relative;  height: 26px;}.art-blockheader h3.t,.art-blockheader h3.t a,.art-blockheader h3.t a:link,.art-blockheader h3.t a:visited, .art-blockheader h3.t a:hover{  color: #000000;  font-size: 14px;}.art-blockheader h3.t{  margin:0;  padding: 0 10px 0 5px;  white-space: nowrap;  line-height: 26px;   }/* end BlockHeader *//* begin Box, BlockContent */.art-blockcontent{  position: relative;  margin: 0 auto;  min-width: 1px;  min-height: 1px;}.art-blockcontent-body{  position: relative;  padding: 5px;}.art-blockcontent-body, .art-blockcontent-body li, .art-blockcontent-body a,.art-blockcontent-body a:link,.art-blockcontent-body a:visited,.art-blockcontent-body a:hover{  color: #000;  font-family: font-family:'RedCircleRegular';;  font-size: 13px;}.art-blockcontent-body p{  margin: 6px 0 6px 0;}.art-blockcontent-body a{  color: #000000;}.art-blockcontent-body a:link{  color: #000000;}.art-blockcontent-body a:visited, .art-blockcontent-body a.visited{  color: #000000;  text-decoration: none;}.art-blockcontent-body a:hover, .art-blockcontent-body a.hover{  color: #000000;  text-decoration: none;}.art-blockcontent-body ul li{  line-height: 125%;      color: #E5F5D1;}/* end Box, BlockContent *//* begin Button */.art-button-wrapper a.art-button,.art-button-wrapper a.art-button:link,.art-button-wrapper input.art-button,.art-button-wrapper button.art-button{  text-decoration: none;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  font-size: 13px;  position:relative;  top:0;  display: inline-block;  vertical-align: middle;  white-space: nowrap;  text-align: center;  color: #FFFFFF !important;  width: auto;  outline: none;  border: none;  background: none;  line-height: 26px;  height: 26px;  margin: 0 !important;  padding: 0 9px !important;  overflow: visible;  cursor: default;}.art-button img, .art-button-wrapper img{  margin: 0;  vertical-align: middle;}.art-button-wrapper{  vertical-align: middle;  display: inline-block;  position: relative;  height: 26px;  overflow: hidden;  white-space: nowrap;  width: auto;  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  z-index: 0;}.firefox2 .art-button-wrapper{  display: block;  float: left;}input, select, textarea{  vertical-align: middle;  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;  font-size: 13px;}.art-block select {    width:96%;}.art-button-wrapper.hover .art-button, .art-button-wrapper.hover a.art-button:link, .art-button:hover{  color: #7F5305 !important;  text-decoration: none !important;}.art-button-wrapper.active .art-button, .art-button-wrapper.active a.art-button:link{  color: #FFFFFF !important;}.art-button-wrapper .art-button-l, .art-button-wrapper .art-button-r{  display: block;  position: absolute;  height: 88px;  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  background-image: url('images/button.png');}.art-button-wrapper .art-button-l{  left: 0;  right: 12px;}.art-button-wrapper .art-button-r{  width: 417px;  right: 0;  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, 405px);}.art-button-wrapper.hover .art-button-l, .art-button-wrapper.hover .art-button-r{  top: -31px;}.art-button-wrapper.active .art-button-l, .art-button-wrapper.active .art-button-r{  top: -62px;}.art-button-wrapper input{  float: none !important;}/* end Button *//* begin Box, Post */.art-post{  position: relative;  margin: 0 auto;  min-width: 1px;  min-height: 1px;}.art-post-body{  position: relative;  padding: 10px;}.art-post{  margin: 0;}a img{  border: 0;}.art-article img, img.art-article{  border: solid 0 #C7EA9A;  margin: 7px;}.art-metadata-icons img{  border: none;  vertical-align: middle;  margin: 2px;}.art-article table, table.art-article{  border-collapse: collapse;  margin: 1px;}.art-article th, .art-article td{  padding: 2px;  border: solid 0px #4C2045;  vertical-align: top;  text-align: left;}.art-article th{  text-align: center;  vertical-align: middle;  padding: 7px;}pre{  overflow: auto;  padding: 0.1em;  float:left;}/* end Box, Post *//* begin PostHeaderIcon */h2.art-postheader{  color: #000000;  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;}h2.art-postheader, h2.art-postheader a, h2.art-postheader a:link, h2.art-postheader a:visited,h2.art-postheader a.visited,h2.art-postheader a:hover,h2.art-postheader a.hovered{  font-size: 24px;}h2.art-postheader a, h2.art-postheader a:link{  text-align: left;  text-decoration: none;  color: #fff;}h2.art-postheader a:visited, h2.art-postheader a.visited{  color: #fff;}h2.art-postheader a:hover,  h2.art-postheader a.hovered{  color: #000000;}/* end PostHeaderIcon *//* begin PostBullets */.art-post ol, .art-post ul{  margin: 1em 0 1em 2em;  padding: 0;}.art-post li{  font-size: 13px;}.art-post li ol, .art-post li ul{  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 2em;  padding: 0;}.art-post li{  color: #1E2E0A;   padding: 0;}/* end PostBullets *//* begin PostQuote */.art-postcontent blockquote,.art-postcontent blockquote a,.art-postcontent blockquote a:link,.art-postcontent blockquote a:visited,.art-postcontent blockquote a:hover{  color: #080D03;  font-style: italic;  font-weight: normal;  text-align: left;}.art-postcontent blockquote p{   margin: 2px 0 2px 15px;}.art-postcontent blockquote{   border: solid 0 #A24494;  margin: 10px 10px 10px 50px;  padding: 2px 2px 2px 35px;  background-color: #7DBD28;  background-image: url('images/postquote.png');  background-position: left top;  background-repeat: no-repeat;/* makes blockquote not to align behind the image if they are in the same line */  overflow: auto;}/* end PostQuote *//* begin Footer */.art-footer{  position: relative;  overflow: hidden;  width: 100%;}.art-footer-t{  position: absolute;  top: 0;  left: 0;  right: 0;  bottom: 0;  background-color: #8CC540;}.art-footer-body{    position:relative;    padding: 5px;}.art-footer-text p{  padding:0;  margin:0;}.art-footer,.art-footer a,.art-footer a:link,.art-footer a:visited,.art-footer a:hover{    color: #131D06;    font-size: 11px;}.art-footer-text{  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;}.art-footer,.art-footer-text,.art-footer p{  text-align: center;}.art-footer a,.art-footer a:link{  color: #6C2D62;  text-decoration: none;}.art-footer a:visited{  color: #537E1B;}.art-footer a:hover{  color: #7DBD28;  text-decoration: underline;}/* end Footer *//* begin PageFooter */.art-page-footer, .art-page-footer a,.art-page-footer a:link,.art-page-footer a:visited,.art-page-footer a:hover{  font-family: Arial;  font-size: 10px;  letter-spacing: normal;  word-spacing: normal;  font-style: normal;  font-weight: normal;  text-decoration: underline;  color: #ADE06C;}.art-page-footer{  margin: 1em;  text-align: center;  text-decoration: none;  color: #ADE06C;}/* end PageFooter *//* begin LayoutCell, sidebar1 */.art-content-layout .art-sidebar1{    background-color: #C7C7C7;    background-image: url("images/sidebar_h.gif");    background-position: right top;    background-repeat: repeat-y;    width: 176px;  }/* end LayoutCell, sidebar1 *//* begin LayoutCell, content *//* end LayoutCell, content *//* begin LayoutCell, sidebar2 */.art-content-layout .art-sidebar2{    background-color: #C7C7C7;    background-image: url("images/sidebar_g.gif");    background-position: left top;    background-repeat: repeat-y;    width: 195px;}/* end LayoutCell, sidebar2 */textarea#comment{width:100%;}.commentlist, .commentlist li{  background: none;}.commentlist li li{  margin-left: 30px;}.commentlist li .avatar{  float: right;  border: 1px solid #eee;  padding: 2px;  margin: 1px;  background: #fff;}.commentlist li cite{  font-size: 1.2em;}#commentform textarea{  width: 100%;}img.wp-smiley{  border: none;  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}.navigation{  display: block;  text-align: center;}/* Recommended by http://codex.wordpress.org/CSS *//* Begin */.aligncenter, div.aligncenter, .art-article .aligncenter img, .aligncenter img.art-article, .aligncenter img, img.aligncenter{  display: block;  margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;}.alignleft{  float: left;}.alignright{  float: right;}.alignright img, img.alignright{  margin: 1em;  margin-right: 0;}.alignleft img, img.alignleft{  margin: 1em;  margin-left: 0;}.wp-caption{  border: 1px solid #ddd;  background-color: #f3f3f3;  padding-top: 4px;  margin: 10px;}.wp-caption img{  margin: 0;  padding: 0;  border: 0 none;}.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text{  font-size: 11px;  line-height: 17px;  padding: 0 4px 5px;  margin: 0;}.wp-caption, .wp-caption p{    text-align: center;}/* End */.hidden{  display: none;}/* Calendar */#wp-calendar {  empty-cells: show;  margin: 10px auto 0;  width: 155px;}#wp-calendar #next a {  padding-right: 10px;  text-align: right;}#wp-calendar #prev a {  padding-left: 10px;  text-align: left;}#wp-calendar a {  display: block;}#wp-calendar caption {  text-align: center;  width: 100%;}#wp-calendar td {  padding: 3px 0;  text-align: center;}.gallery {  letter-spacing: normal;}.art-content {  position: relative;  z-index: 1;   }#todays-events{  position: relative;  z-index: 11;    }#upcoming-events{  position: relative;  z-index: 10;    }img.wp-post-image {    margin:0 5px 5px 0 !important;}div.art-footer li, ul.commentlist li{    list-style-image: none;    background:none;    list-style-type:none;    }div.art-footer div.art-content-layout,  div.art-content div.art-content-layout{    margin:0 auto;    width:100%;}div.art-footer ul{    padding-left: 0;}div.art-footer ul li ul{    padding-left: 20px;}div.art-layout-cell-size1 {    width:100%;}div.art-layout-cell-size2 {    width:50%;}div.art-layout-cell-size3 {    width:33%;}div.art-layout-cell-size4{    width:25%;}div.art-author-info img.avatar {    float:left;     margin-top:0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [fontsquirrel](http://fontsquirrel.com)

Comment: I did use that service to get me started, which is why I am so confused as to why it is not working.

Comment: So you didn't do it right. Copy exactly the same code as you get in generated archive.

Comment: I put the fonts in the root and that seemed to fix it. Thank you for the comments.